# tesseract OCR giving no output and no diagnostics

Tags: tesseract-ocr

I've used `tesseract` for OCR a few times in the past successfully.  On macOS; it was installed by "home-brew"

Today, I did

```
WGroleau@MBP ~ % brew upgrade # to make sure everything is the latest and then …
WGroleau@MBP ~ % tesseract ~/Downloads/temp.jpg stdout -l chi_sim
福佳生活饶
```

The last (fifth) character was incorrect, so I made a minor graphic edit to that character and ran the same command.  No output, no diagnostics.  Ran it verbose—still no diagnostics, only what libraries it used.

Cropped the edited character out of the file and tried.  Still no output, no diagnostics.

**What do I do next?**

Here's the file after edit but before cropping:[image]

**Update:** If I tell it to use "Legacy engine only," I get:

```
Error: Tesseract (legacy) engine requested, but components are not present in /usr/local/share/tessdata/chi_sim.traineddata!!
Failed loading language 'chi_sim'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.
```

Comment: Do you still have access to the original `temp.jpg`? What if you edit it in a different program? Or even re-save the current file using a different program. I mean it looks like the first program saved the jpg in a form that triggers some bug(?) in `tesseract`. If another program manages to produce a "more compatible" jpg then the simplest workaround will be to use it instead of the first program when editing for `tesseract`.

Comment: 'temp.jpg' is the name I overwrite almost daily for throwaway items. I don't have another graphic editor. But I've used GraphicConverter many times this way with another OCR and twice successfully with tesseract.  Doing it today _does_ get a diagnostic—a usage screen as if no filename was provided.

Answer (score 0):

Tried adding the option `--psm 13` and it worked.  Don’t get why it worked two or more times before on .jpg saved by the same program.  Nor why there isn't a diagnostic message when it silently fails (first instance) or a false one on the second instance.